# Remove duplicate object copies from array of objects

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that I get from an API. The property names are dynamic (meaning I don't have an extensive list of all of them). How can I get an array of all distinct objects? The contract specifies that if key is equal value is also equal. I tried to look around but I found nothing quite like this problem.

```
[                                                                                                                                                                                           20:31:28
  {
    'product-management': 'Product management'
  },
  {
    'product-development': 'Product development'
  },
  {
    'client-work': 'Client work'
  },
  {
    'client-work': 'Client work'
  },
  {
    'product-development': 'Product development'
  },
  {
    'client-work': 'Client work'
  },
  {
    'product-development': 'Product development'
  }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest using a different structure, with `{key: '…', value: '…' }`-shaped objects.

Comment: can't do that :(

Comment: Sure you can. Even if the API responds with this weird JSON, you can still transform it into something more sane locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the array into `Object.assign()` to merge all objects to a single one. Since all objects properties are unique, this will leave only one key (and value) from the duplicates. Then convert to [key, value] pairs with `Object.entries()`, and map back to individual objects:

```js
const data = [{"product-management":"Product management"},{"product-development":"Product development"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"product-development":"Product development"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"product-development":"Product development"}]

const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...data))
  .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
  
console.log(result)
```

Going with [@Bergi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448561/remove-duplicate-object-copies-from-array-of-objects/59448609#comment105079715_59448561), you can also convert this to a saner API while removing duplicates:

```js
const data = [{"product-management":"Product management"},{"product-development":"Product development"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"product-development":"Product development"},{"client-work":"Client work"},{"product-development":"Product development"}]

const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...data))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }))
  
console.log(result)
```